# Proving that support of a measure is a carrier

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am reading Introduction to Model Spaces and their operators by Garcia, Mashreghi and Ross. In first page, the authors define what a support and carrier of a measure. The measures considered here are on the unit circle denoted by $\mathbb T$ and defined by $\mathbb T = \{ z\in \mathbb C : \lvert z \rvert =1 \}$. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb T$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open arcs of $\mathbb T$.

Now, for a finite positive measure on $\mu$ on Borel $\sigma$-algebra, the support is defined to be the the complement of the union of all open subsets of $\mathbb T$ which have measure $0$. A Borel set $E \subset \mathbb T$ is called a carrier of $\mu$ if $\mu (E \cap A)=\mu (A)$ for each Borel subset $A$.

The authors claim thatthe support of $\mu$ is a carrier but I am unable to see how. Here's my attempt:

Let $\mathcal S$ denote the support of the measure $\mu$. Let $A$ be a Borel set of $\mathbb T$. We wish to show that $\mu (\mathcal S \cap A) = \mu (A)$. It is obvious that $\mu (\mathcal S \cap A) \le \mu (A)$. One needs to check that $\mu (\mathcal S \cap A) \ge \mu (A)$.

It is easy to see that $\mu (\mathcal S \cap A ) = \mu \left(\bigcap \left\{ A \cap F : F \text{ is a closed set satisfying } \mu(\mathbb T) =\mu (F)  \right\}\right)$. I do not see how to proceed from here. Hints will be appreciated!

---

EDIT: Here's my attempt: After receiving a hint: I will show that the complement support is of measure $0$. Let $\mathcal U$ be the complement of the support. Since $\mathcal U$ is a open set in $\mathbb T$, $\mathcal U$ is countable union of open arcs $\mathcal C_i$ (one can mimic the same proof as that of for $\mathbb R$ [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935664/every-open-set-in-r-is-the-countable-union-of-open-intervals-open)). Since the open arcs contained in $\cal U$  must be of measure zero by definition of $\mathcal U$, we have that
\begin{align*}
\mu (\mathcal U) = \mu(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathcal C_i) \le \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(\mathcal C_i) = 0.
\end{align*}

To finish the proof, notice that $\mu(A) = \mu(A \cap \mathcal S) + \mu (A \cap \mathcal U) \le \mu(A \cap \mathcal S) + \mu (\mathcal U)= \mu (A \cap \mathcal S)$.

Comment: Try showing $\mu(\mathbb{T}\setminus \mathcal{S})=0$.

Comment: @FZan Can you take a look at my attempt now? I have updated my question.

Comment: It looks good now.